Kickstart file: Where should liveimg --url point to?
I am trying to build a oracle linux 8 virtual machine image without manual intervention. Currently I have a kickstart file with liveimg --url=file:///images/install.img set. I've have the boot.iso on /mnt, and passed in parameters to virt-install like this.
sudo virt-install --name oracle8 --ram 4096 --disk /dev/xvdf --vcpus 2 --os-type linux --os-variant ol8.0 --network bridge=virbr0 --noreboot --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location '/mnt/boot.iso' --extra-args 'inst.notmux inst.cmdline console=ttyS0,115200n8 inst.ks=file:/oracle.ks' --initrd-inject=/home/user/oracle.ks"

However, my installation is ending in failure with the following errors.
Non interactive installation failed: file does not exist: file:///images/install.img

My question is how do I get the images/install.img from boot.iso and pass it to liveimg --url? Is there a specific directory location on the host where I should mount it?
